# Views Data Export for Larger Files fails

Tags: php, excel, drupal, export

I am using Views Data Export library to generate excel data based on result from the view. View results in 10000+ rows. But the export doesn't work; it is showing a blank page. I have increased my memory limit to 1000 MB in php.ini and also in settings.php. But when echoed it shows peak memory to more than 1000 MB. I can only provide 1000 MB max for memory limit.

Could you please suggest something or any alternative?.

Answer (score 4):

You can use batch option which was available in views data export module, you can export all your data i.e 10000+ in a single csv or excel file by batch processing the result as the per the limit your are configuring in the view under Data Export Setting. Please find the screen-shot for the configuration which I did for my project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a problem you can **break the view results with a pager** (for example of 1000 rows) and export the results for each page. This will reduce the memory requirements as also as the excel file size.

Comment: I want to export all the result to a single file. Is it possible?

Comment: Does the views query work if you display it on a page display?